# Django. Unbound method in urls

Tags: python, django

I trying to accept localhost:8000/upload file and run into this problem

unbound method upload_file() must be called with Upload instance as first argument (got WSGIRequest instance instead)

*urls.py*

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

from upload.views import Upload


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^upload/$', Upload.upload_file),
    url(r'^thanks/$', Upload.thanks),
]
```

*views.py*

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext

from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from upload.forms import FileForm

from upload.models import upFile

class Upload():

    def upload_file(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = FileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('thanks')
        else:
            form = FileForm()

        return render_to_response('temp1.html', {'form': form}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))

    def thanks(request):
        return render_to_response('temp2.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your view is not inheriting from a Django class based view: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/intro/

```
from django.views.generic import View


class Upload(View):
    def upload_file(self, request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = FileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('thanks')
        else:
            form = FileForm()

        return render_to_response('temp1.html', {'form': form}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))

    def thanks(self, request):
        return render_to_response('temp2.html')
```

You need to inherit form one of these view classes otherwise Django will treat your view as a normal class which is why you are getting that error.

you also need to adjust your urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^upload/', Upload.as_view()),
]
```

After looking through the docs and at the structure of your vie I'm not sure you are structuring your views properly for class based views. You may want to read through the docs some more and adjust your structure accordingly.

I believe you will want somethign that looks more like this:

```
class Upload(View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = FileForm()
        return render_to_response('temp1.html', {'form': form}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))

    def post(self, request):
        form = FileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('thanks')
        else:
            return render_to_response('temp2.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you have the Upload class at all. Python is not Java, there's no need to put everything into classes. Put `upload_file` and `thanks` at the module level, and refer to them directly in the url patterns.